# Error installing ffi

Tags: ruby, linux, ffi

Can seem to get around this.

```
$gem install ffi
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ffi:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/remote/part/usern/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for ffi.h... no
checking for ffi.h in /usr/local/include,/usr/include/ffi... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_with_gvl()... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl()... yes
checking for ffi_prep_cif_var()... no
creating extconf.h
creating Makefile

make
libffi.gnu.mk:16: Extraneous text after `else' directive
libffi.gnu.mk:18: *** only one `else' per conditional.  Stop.


Gem files will remain installed in /remote/part/usern/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@myrailsapp/gems/ffi-1.9.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /remote/part/usern/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@myrailsapp/gems/ffi-1.9.0/ext/ffi_c/gem_make.out
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Install `libffi-dev`.  What distribution is this?

Comment: Try `yum install libffi-devel`

Comment: I get - This system is not registered with RHN.
RHN support will be disabled.
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Setting up Install Process
No package libffi-devel available.
Nothing to do

Comment: Ensure EPEL is enabled. then yum install rubygem-ffi

Answer (score 1):

try this before

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.2
apt-get install ruby{version}-dev

bundle install ffi
```

it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I had to set the gcc to 4.2  and it worked. I also changed the ffi version to 1.0.9 in Gemfile.lock.

export PATH=/opt/gcc-4.2.0/bin/:$PATH

Answer (score 0):

Hi that's related with the GCC compiler i updated mine and also did the trick that Harpreet mentioned (ffi version downgrade) BUT it's not necessary ffi-1.9.3 worked just fine as well :D

in the Gemfile.lock

```
    ffi (1.9.3)
    ffi (1.9.3-x86-mingw32)
```

https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer

[click here github repo with the .pkg installer for all OS (not only MacOSX)](https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer)